# I have shell script which accepts two date parameters and needs to validate two parameters in the dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have shell script which accepts two date parameters and needs to validate two parameters in the dd-mm-yyyy format.
....

```
DateValidate () {
                date "+%d-%m-%Y" -d "$1" > /dev/null  2>&1
                is_valid1=$?
                date "+%d-%m-%Y" -d "$2" > /dev/null  2>&1
                is_valid2=$?
                if [[ "$is_valid1" != 0  ||  "${is_valid2}" != 0 ]];
                   echo "invalid dates"
                else echo "passed valid arguments"
```

.........

Getting invalid dates but if when I do this with date "+%Y-%m-%d" then it is validating fine, please let me know any way to validate the date arguments format as ddmmyyyy.

Comment: inside your function reformat `$1` and `$2` to `YYYY-MM-DD` before calling `date`

Comment: What is the format of arguments that are passed as `$1` and `$2`?

Comment: You should use `-ne` to test numeric inequality, `!=` tests string inequality. (nit) You do not need to quote variables inside `[[ ... ]]` you must with `[ ... ]` and `test`. Be consistent in your use of variable name guarding, e.g.  `$is_valid1` and `${is_valid2}` looks awkward though perfectly fine.

Comment: @Naidu5: Why do you supply a date format, which is only for formatting a date for writing to stdout, if you dump the stdout afterwards. Otherwise your approach is not plain wrong; it just validates for **any** format which `date` accepts and should output _invalid dates_ if one of the dates supplied isn't decodable by `date`. But  the error message you are printing, is misleading. It should be instead:  _One of your dates is invalid, but I won't tell you which_. Also, I would not throw away stderr while debugging the script, because it might provide additional information what's going wrong.

Comment: @Naidu5 : Look at the `data` man page for the paragraph titled _DATE STRING_. It describes roughly, what format is expected for specifying the date.

Answer (score 2):

Your primary problem is, while `date` will handle a wide range of formats with `-d` it will not take hyphen separated values as `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy`. In a delimited format `date` expects `mm/dd/yyyy`. So you will have to reformat your date in that format before attempting conversion with `date -d`.

You should also validate you have the proper number of inputs as well as using `local` variables within your function. Adding the validations and using `awk` for a quick reformat of the arguments, you could do:

```
validdate() {
    [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ] && { ## validate 2 arguments given
        printf "error: insufficient no. of arguments.\n" >&2
        return 1
    }
    ## reformat dd-mm-yyyy as mm/dd/yyyy
    local d1=$(awk -F- '{ print $2"/"$1"/"$3 }' <<< "$1")
    local d2=$(awk -F- '{ print $2"/"$1"/"$3 }' <<< "$2")
    ## conversion to date
    date -d "$d1" &>/dev/null || { printf "date1 invalid\n" >&2; return 1; }
    date -d "$d2" &>/dev/null || { printf "date2 invalid\n" >&2; return 1; }
    
    echo "dates valid"
    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** if not using bash, you will need to replace the *herestring* `<<<` with a pipe.)

Adding a short script to check the input:

```
validdate "$1" "$2"
echo "return $?"
```

The function performs as you intend, e.g.

```
$ ./chkdates.sh 21-4-1999 23-5-1999
dates valid
return 0
```

Or in the case of an invalid date:

```
$ ./chkdates.sh 21-4-1999 32-5-1999
date2 invalid
return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to `date -d` cannot be provided in the dd-mm-yyyy format. Before using `date -d`, you have to convert your date parameters into a format that `date -d` can handle. The following works, by converting the two date parameters to the yyyymmdd format:

```
#! /bin/bash

validate () {
    day="$(cut -d'-' -f1 <<<$1)"
    month="$(cut -d'-' -f2 <<<$1)"
    year="$(cut -d'-' -f3 <<<$1)"
    date "+%d%m%y" -d $year$month$day > /dev/null  2>&1
}

validate $1
is_valid1=$?
validate $2
is_valid2=$?

if [[ "$is_valid1" != 0  ||  "${is_valid2}" != 0 ]]
then
   echo "Invalid dates"
fi
```

Example:

```
./datevalid_test.sh 28-17-2020 14-04-2018
Invalid dates
```

To calculate the difference between two dates (in days), you can use:

```
#! /bin/bash

convert_to_seconds() {
    day="$(cut -d'-' -f1 <<<$1)"
    month="$(cut -d'-' -f2 <<<$1)"
    year="$(cut -d'-' -f3 <<<$1)"
    echo "$(date "+%s" -d $year$month$day)"    
}

fdate="$(convert_to_seconds $1)"
sdate="$(convert_to_seconds $2)"
period=$((60*60*24)) 
datediff=$(((${fdate} - ${sdate})/${period})) 
echo $datediff
```

This will calculate the difference between two dates provided in dd-mm-yyyy format, again by converting each date parameter to the yyyymmdd format. Example:

```
./datediff_test.sh 30-07-2020 28-07-2020
2
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24636/334354 for more info on how to calculate date differences.

Comment: Thanks for the help now I am passing this parameters to calculate dates difference but getting invalid date formats while calculating at datesdiff() funcion., dates diff funtion below. ......DateDiff () {
  ##Calculating the difference in dates
  fdate=$(date -d "$date1" "+%s")
        sdate=$(date -d "$date2" "+%s")
     period=$((60*60*24))
        datediff=$(( (${fdate} - ${sdate})/(${period}) ))
        echo $datediff
Please help how again I have to calculate date difference in ddmmyyyy format only.

Comment: You need to make sure that the date parameters are converted into the yyyymmdd format before executing the `date` commands. I will update my answer to show how to calculate the difference between two dates.

Comment: No problem, please upvote my answer if you feel it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@tomptz, thanks for the help and below code works.

```
....
#! /bin/bash

convert_to_seconds() {
    day="$(cut -d'-' -f1 <<<$1)"
    month="$(cut -d'-' -f2 <<<$1)"
    year="$(cut -d'-' -f3 <<<$1)"
    echo "$(date "+%s" -d $year$month$day)"    
}

fdate="$(convert_to_seconds $1)"
sdate="$(convert_to_seconds $2)"
period=$((60*60*24)) 
datediff=$(((${fdate} - ${sdate})/${period})) 
echo $datediff
....
```

Comment: No problem, please upvote my answer below if you feel it solves your problem.